# PHP Regex - Strip Out All Non Numbers and Decimals

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, I am trying to strip out everything from the price except for numbers and the decimal point associated to the number. With my current regex expression, I am having trouble trying to determine if the decimal is associated to the numeric value or the currency symbol. Any ideas?

`preg_replace('/[^(0-9).]/', '', $price)`

Test Values => Expected Values

1. $43.99  =>   43.99
2. ฿2,320.00 => 2320.00
3. kr. 479.00 => 479.00
4. 1 999 руб. => 1999

Comment: remove the parenthesis from your character class unless you want to allow `(` and `)` as valid characters.

Comment: This should do the trick: `[^\d\.]`

Comment: If the decimal trails the number, that shouldn't be a problem because the number would just be treating as a whole number. I would likely just do what you are doing and then cast to a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with

```
'/[^\d.]|(?<!\d)\./'
```

It matches non-digits and non-periods or periods that are not preceded with a digit. Then, just replace with empty string to remove the matched text.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/aZgZmn):

```
$re = '/[^\d.]|(?<!\d)\./'; 
$ar = array("\$43.99", "฿2,320.00", "kr. 479.00", "1 999 руб."); 
$result = preg_filter($re, "", $ar);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
[0] => 43.99
[1] => 2320.00
[2] => 479.00
[3] => 1999
```

A [`preg_replace` demo](http://ideone.com/9982KY):

```
$re = '/[^\d.\n]|(?<!\d)\./'; // \n is added just for demo purposes! 
$str = "\$43.99\n฿2,320.00\nkr. 479.00\n1 999 руб."; 
echo $result = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```